# How to justify short text inside fill fixed width parent with CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image: target]
This is my target

[image: CSS like this]

try to add text-align

[image: but End up with this]

but seems the text is not long enough.

How can I make short text fill their parent's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if text-align only works with text that exceeds the line.
You could use flexbox to work around that.
Though it would require you to wrap every word in a span. Not sure where you intend to use it, but if it is only in one area, with 6 words, it may work for you.

```
<div class="parent">
  <p><span>bla</span> <span>bla</span> <span>bla</span></p>
</div>


//Mixins
@mixin flexbox($direction, $wrap, $justify, $align){
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: $direction;
    flex-wrap: $wrap;
    justify-content: $justify;
    align-items: $align;
}

.parent{
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;

  p{
    text-align: justify;
    @include flexbox(row, wrap, space-between, center)
  }
}
```

U can see it live here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xtLIG

Answer (score 0):

You may try increasing the word spacing.

For eg:

```
.myClass{
word-spacing:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `letter-spacing: 20px;` play with the number till you got the right width.
Or `word-spacing: 20px;`